# Fit Flash webpage in the browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, web

I am working on a website in Adobe Flash CS6. I gave my documents a size of 1024 px x 768 px. But when I publish the cwebsite, I don't know how to make the flash document to have the browser size... Take for example: incontextediting.adobe.com. It is fully designed in Flash, but it has the browser's dimensions. How to achieve that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do these arrangments in Flash side

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

and you have to resize every thing with your resize algoritm with this event listener:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, function(event:Event):void{
ExampleObject.x = Math.floor(stage.stageWidth/2 - ExampleObject.width/2);
ExampleObject.y = Math.floor(stage.stageHeight/2 - ExampleObject.height/2);
/*
For example: 
Centering an object
*/
});
```

And of course you have to do some browser-side arrangments. I use swffit and swfobject combined,

http://code.google.com/p/swffit

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject

Answer (score 2):

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
```

This code make your application to no-scale mode. In `onResize` handler your must write code which fit components and graphics to current screen size. Stage width and height available in `Stage.stageWidth and Stage.stageHeight` properties

Comment: also make sure that the html that div or whatever that contains the swf is 100% width and height.

Comment: @csomakk Also make sure to set margin and padding for html and body to 0